# Aux und Output files in another directory puzzles TeXstudio

Tags: warnings, texstudio, auxiliary-files, output, folders

I have configured my TeX runs to save all aux and output files into a 'temp' subdirectory using the 'output-directory' option of lualatex in TeXlive.

Everything works wonderful, Biber and Makeglossaries are running etc. The PDF also looks nice.

But TeXstudio displays a lot of errors and warnings (without them occurring in the logfile or being actually true). There are some "undefined control sequences", "no file *.acr" (from glossaries), "undefined references", "label(s) may have changed", "please (re)run biber" and so on.
As said, they only appear in TeXstudio, not in the log file. And all those references, the bibliography, the glossary and so on are perfect in the PDF.

I could just ignore them but then I miss the real warnings that I want to take care about since they are hidden between hundreds of wrong warnings.

Any ideas how to solve this?

For your insights, I run the following commands for compilation. $1 is the argument my bash script gets, meaning the master file name:

```
    # LuaLatex
    lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=./temp --shell-escape $1
    # Biber
    cp ./general/literatur.bib ./temp/general
    biber ./temp/$1
    # Makeglossaries
    makeglossaries -d ./temp $1
    # LuaLatex
    lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=./temp --shell-escape $1
    lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=./temp --shell-escape $1
```

Comment: Mmhh, today after starting TeXstudio no warnings and errors are displayed at all but instead the message that no log file can be found. Strange that it behaves differently from yesterday. However, this is even worse of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I could solve this by adding this specific './temp' directory to Settings -> Build -> Search Paths. Then the correct warnings are shown again, no additional clutter.

Adding txs:///view-log to my user command was necessary additionally in order to get the log file updates instead of loaded only the first time.

Comment: Well, I have to correct myself again. It only loaded the log file once.
Seems that TeXstudio has problems when I call an external bash script for building instead of using the internal build functions. So it's the same behaviour if I put the output files into a subdirectory or not... :(

Comment: Seems that this is the reason why no new log is loaded after calling a build script instead of using the internal routines:
http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/695

Comment: I have just filed a feature request: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/901/