# Texstudio + Biber + build folder

Tags: biber, auxiliary-files

I used [this tutorial](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Tips-And-Tricks#user-content-using-a-separate-directory-for-auxiliary-files) to export my auxiliary files into a different directory.

Basically i just add `-aux-directory=build` in `Options -> Configure -> Commands` and added the `build` folder into `Options -> Configure -> Build -> Build Options -> Additional Search Paths -> Log`.

This succesfully generates all the auxilliary files in the build folder and it's also possible to generate the pdf.

Unfortunately biber has a problem with this setup:

> Prozess gestartet: biber.exe "MyFile"
>
> INFO - This is Biber 1.7
>
> INFO - Logfile is 'MyFile.blg'
>
> ERROR - Cannot find control file 'MyFile.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
>
> INFO - ERRORS: 1

I guess i have to specify the correct path for biber somewhere in Texstudio. Does anyone know where i have to update the path?

[In this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158745/aux-und-output-files-in-another-directory-puzzles-texstudio) someone had similar problems. Also i'm not sure if the solution of [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/placing-intermediate-and-output-files-in-another-folder)  applies to my situation.

Comment: `biber --help` includes the following information: `--output_directory [directory]`
        Files (`.bbl` and `.blg`) are output to directory `directory` instead of
        the current directory. **Input files are also looked for in `directory`
        before current directory.** [My emphasis.]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Solution to use Texstudio and output the build (temporary) files into a seperate folder using biber:

1. Put a new Folder with `YourName` into the same directory as your main .tex file.
2. `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Commands -> PdfLaTeX` for *MiKTeX* add `-aux-directory=YourName`.
   If you use *TeX Live* use `-output-directory YourName`.
   Result looks something like this: `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory= build %.tex` respectively `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build %.tex`
3. `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Commands -> Biber` add `--output_directory YourName`. Result looks something like this: `biber.exe --output_directory build %` (careful: i think the space between the name and % is mandatory)
4. In `Configure TeXstudio` bottom left corner activate the `Show Advanced Options` checkbox. Add your folder to `Configure TeXstudio -> Build -> Additional Search Paths` with `.\YourName` (or complete path)

Thanks @cfr for the solution!

Comment: The `-aux-directory=DIR` option is specific to MiKTeX. I think you should mention that in your answer. In TeXlive there is only the `-output-directory=DIR` option. But it is still possible to achieve a separate output-directory for the `.pdf`-file as described in the commend to the question [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96767/mactex-aux-directory-dir] but it involves using a hard link.

Answer (score 11):

(EDIT: Adding Biber)

For MiKTeX with TeXstudio, go to Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Commands:

1. PdfLaTeX: `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --aux-directory=build %.tex`
2. BibTeX: `bibtex.exe build/% -include-directory=build`
3. Biber: `biber.exe --output-directory build %`

Copy and paste the above codes in the configuration page.

The above configuration will create a new *subfolder* in your working directory named "build" where all aux/log/out files will be created/saved there as well as Bibtex's and Biber's (except for synctex.gz). The  working folder will be cleaner specially if you are doing a big project with a lot of sub .tex files (e.g. chapters ... etc, used with include or input).

Comment: this finally worked for me thanks!, is it possible to get the file.pdf and the file.synctex in the build folder also ? I tried in PdfLatex using -output-directoy.... but I get error when it tries to search for the pdf to visualize bc it keeps looking in the main folder not in build

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use build folders and stumbling again and again into problems with each tool, the LaTeX build wrapper [ltx2any](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) may be a better solution. One of its main features is

> Keeps your main directory clean by default.

This goal is achieved by not compiling in the main folder but copying all required files into a temporary folder and compiling the document there. This avoids all the problems associated with build folders.

---

The basic usage is

```
ltx2any filename.tex
```

and all the auxiliary files will be in a subdirectory. For more options read the linked webpage or run `ltx2any --help`.