# Can I specify an output path into the TeX file for generated PDF?

Tags: pdf, texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio and I defined my command to copy the generated 
PDF into another directory:

```
cmd /C copy %.pdf C:\Users\me\myLatex\pdf
```

and all works fine.

Now I would like to specify the output path into the `.tex` file;
namely, I would like to do this:

```
cmd /C copy %.pdf outputDirectory
```

and in the TEX file something like (the following line does not make sense, is just to explain what I want to do):

```
\define outputDirectory = C:\Users\me\myLatex\pdf
```

in order to specify different output path for each document.

Comment: It's unclear to me how/where do you use the copy command you defined: as a shell-escape, augmented to TeXstudio build commands or else ... Maybe you can add an MWE as well.

Comment: I found that command in this answer: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187672/path-for-saving-pdf-in-texstudio

Comment: You can place a commented line in your main `.tex` source -- like for example `% outputdirectory = C:\my\preferred\path\for\this\pdf `. Then you can create a batch file that takes `%.tex` as argument, searches in it for a line containing `% outputdirectory =`, strips the searched string from the result (or similar way to get only the path you set) and passes it to a copy command. Then use the batch file in TeXstudio same as you set the plain copy command. Of course, you need to take care of missing/invalid path, overwriting/renaming.

Comment: @alwaysask, it would be great if you could put an example of simple Tex file and batch file to follow clearly the steps.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Take any of your tex files and add this line, say as the first line, before \documentclass{...}: `% outputDirectory = C:\Users\me\myLatex\pdf` or any other keyword combination you like. As for the batch file, sorry, can't help because: (1) I don't a have a Windows OS and (2) it's offtopic on this site (try http://stackoverflow.com -- {batch-file} is the tag to look for).

Comment: thank you for your help; i wrote a simple java app which is called every time i compile the .tex file and i set the source and the destination path in the main.tex as @alwaysask suggested

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can specify both PDF and auxiliary files output directories by PDFLatex options.

In [MiKTeX manual](http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/doc/2.9/miktex.pdf), you can specify the output directory of your PDF file (through the option `--output-directory`) in addition to your auxiliary files one (through the option `--aux-directory`).

You can follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184285/2288) steps to understand where to input these options.