# BibTex fails on opening database "-blx" file

Tags: bibtex

I'm kind of new here. I googled for hours this evening, frustratingly looking for an answer to my problems.

So I compile like this:
pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex -> pdfview
I use TexMaker, i have a build folder ,etc etc. I started using a build folder because I saw it being advised to people with similar problems, I didn't have one before.

So my file is test.tex.
When i use pdflatex, it creates a test.aux in the /build folder. Following this, bibtex goes to check in this file and sees this:

```
\relax 
\bibstyle{biblatex}
\bibdata{test-blx,test}
```

Then for some strange reason BibTex can't find test-blx.bib  although it is there, it's created by pdflatex. The error i get is this one:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: build\test.aux The style file: biblatex.bst I couldn't open database file test-blx.bib ---line 3 of file build\test.aux : \bibdata{test-blx : ,test} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files---while reading file build\test.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "biblatex-control" Biblatex version: 3.0 (There were 2 error messages)

Process exited normally
```

And then i goes further downhill.

The test file i created looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{test.bib}
\begin{document}

jan piet joris en korneel ze hebben baarden en hipsterstaartjes\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

Using a different approach (biber,etc) is not a solution to my problem.

Thanks

EDIT: just to make sure: I had the problem before, when i wasn't using a build folder, as well. Bibtex can find the aux file that is created in the build folder without trouble.

EDIT2: so i played around with it some more. recreating my article in a new file seemed to fix the problem, but moving this recreated article to the folder of my original article messed things up again. So right now it seems that placing my .tex files in my dropbox folder (i always work in a cloud environment for safety) will cause bibtex to fail, very strange.

Comment: `test-blx.bib` is an automatically generated file. It should be in your local working directory after the 1st `pdflatex` run already.

Comment: Welcome! Don't use a separate build directory unless you really know what you are doing and are prepared to cope with the frustrations. You need the generated files in your working directory so that everything is found properly. Probably it just can't find stuff in the other directory.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184204/texstudio-biber-build-folder. It should be similiar to TeXmaker