# Biblatex not printing bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker, biber

I cannot manage to print bibliography with Biblatex, and `\cite{XXX}` just provides **XXX** in text.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{blablabla}
\lipsum[1-2] \cite{Campbell2004}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography.bib:

```
@book{Morgan2005,
author = {Morgan, Peter},
isbn = {978-0-8247-0983-9},
issn = {0-8247-0983-7},
publisher = {Taylor {\&} Francis Group, LLC},
title = {{Carbon fibers and their composites}},
year = {2005}
}
```

I'm using MiKTeX portable 2.9, Texmaker 4.5. Already tried:

- Using biber and bibtex as backend;
- Cleaning temp files;
- Already running pdflatex -> Bib(la)tex -> pdflatex (x2);
- bibliography.bib is already a part of the structure and provides quick link.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Nowadays it is preferable to use Biber, you will have to tell your editor about it, though [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). The error message from BibTeX suggests you use a 'build' folder. I suggest you don't do that, then things should work without further modifications.

Comment: Looks as if you changed the build process and tried to move files to some output folder `build` but didn't do it correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I already corrected that error. Still get the same result..

Comment: If you *must* have a build folder, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184204/35864

Comment: You can try to compile the MWEB here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/124842

Comment: Then you didn't corrected it correctly ... If bibtex is looking in the wrong folder for the aux-file then this is caused by a configuration error in your editor. As a check try to compile your document e.g. with texworks or on a command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, the error isn't there anymore, the aux one. I had build subdirectory on, but when I removed it, that particular error was gone.

Comment: @Bobyandbob, just tried to compile the MEWB in that link and didn't worked. Undefined citation, in spite of the .bib file being on the structure.

In fact, while the option of build directory is off, I tried a new file in other directory and it still says that I don't have a file on build directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all @UlrikeFischer was right.

Texmaker still was trying to find the aux file in the directory /build, even with that option disabled. Had to manually delete that in Options.

Thank you very much!