# Comparable LaTex editors to Texpad on Windows

Tags: windows, mac, editors

I know there have been discussions on what editors to use in general. However, I have a specific question about comparable tex editor to Texpad on Windows.

I am a mac user and I am thinking about switching to a windows system. However, `Texpad` is the only thing I am using that is not available on `Windows`. I tried a few editors on PC but none of them comes close to `Texpad`. I have three main concerns:

1. Auto sense and auto typeset -- `Texpad` detects changes to tex codes automatically and compile by itself to reflect those changes
2. Error detecting -- `Texpad` detects errors very well, often point you to the line where the problem comes from
3. No multiple files -- Some windows editors I have tried produce multiple files in addition to pdf once I compile.

Any suggestion would be helpful. I am aware of some of the online editors such as `ShareLatex`, but it is hard to update figures and tables with those editors. I also like work things offline from time to time.

Comment: editors don't generate multiple files, latex creates (and needs) them. Perhaps texpad moves them to a subdirectory? any editor or script could do that (although I always recommend not doing so:-)

Comment: I don't know how Texpad should enhance error detection from TeX's. Every editor shows you on which line which error was as that is part of TeX's error output. And I won't consider your first point as something good. It moves to much attention away from the contents to the looks of your document, imho.

Comment: @Skillmon the question is about what would be a suitable substitute. It's not about whether the properties are good or bad. For example, some people seem to like an editor with a very obscure way of exiting, while others like an editor that acts as an OS, but who are we to decide which is better... :)

Comment: @AlanMunn and my point was that at least one point should be covered by every possible editor and one point might not be that high in priorities (of course I don't want to tell OP what he should do with his life). TeXstudio can at least handle all those auxiliary files in another folder for a cleaner structure https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184204/117050, the error display is decent from what I viewed on colleagues' laptops, don't know about the auto compile though.

Comment: @JamesH Have you tried Lyx which compiles displays equations being written? A slideshow presentation is here: wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LyX/Screencasts/LyXIntroPalette.htm

Comment: @AndréC yesterday I have tried Lyx, but it not the same as a Latex editor. The auto compile gives you a sense of how long your paragraph, how many pages etc.

Comment: It is really sad there is no comparable editor on PC. If you haven't used Texpad on Mac, you should really try. It makes a huge difference in my opinion. It is the only thing that I use my mac for nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the authors of Texpad are working on a Windows version of their editor.  It is not available for beta testing yet.

I can't wait myself as I have to work on a Windows computer at work.

Comment: Right now, this seems more like a comment. Do you have any sources that confirm your claim?

Comment: See the reply to https://twitter.com/fairmath/status/1003864446765228032