# Biber not running on my Texmaker

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I  am trying to run the following latex document, my `biber` has been set up well in Texmaker

[image: Biber set up in Texmaker]

but get an error when I compile:

[image: Running document through Texmaker]

Here is the error I am getting from Texmaker:

> ERROR - Cannot find control file 'Chapter 2.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber? INFO - ERRORS: 1

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
citestyle=numeric, 
natbib=true,
sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabulary}
%\bibliography{thesis} % or
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=true,
 citecolor=Blue,
 linkcolor=Blue,
 urlcolor=Red
}
\hypersetup{ 
citebordercolor=.1 1 .1, 
linkbordercolor=1 0 0, 
 urlbordercolor=1 0 0, }
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set the margins to 1in on all sides
\usepackage{graphicx}              % to include figures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}               % great math stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}              % for blackboard bold, etc
\usepackage{amsthm}                % better theorem \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{mcode}
%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
% various theorems, numbered by section
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
% numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} % same for example numbers

\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\newcommand{\bd}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}  % for bolding symbols
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}      % for Real numbers
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}      % for Integers
\newcommand{\col}[1]{\left[\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right]}
\newcommand{\comb}[2]{\binom{#1^2 + #2^2}{#1+#2}}
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There is another version of `biber.exe`, in `MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\`. Did you try using this one?

Comment: Yes @Bernard, I deleted it and restarted the computer, still the same error. What should I DO?

Comment: You are using a 'build' subdirectory, which means that LaTeX moves the temporary files into a separate subdirectory. When Biber is run it then can't find these files because they aren't where they usually are. The best solution in my book is not to use a build directory.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184204/35864

Comment: Any news here? Did the link help?

Comment: yes @moewe, the link helped thank you very much