# TexStudio build files in subfolder on a Mac

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, mac

Looking for some help, most things I find don't seem to work and cause an error. Not sure if because a lot of them are from ~ 2006 kind of age or because i'm on a Mac.

I'm using TexStudio and BibTex. Want to get all the build files into a subfolder so I can set that folder not to sync to cloud. Everytime I build OneDrive proccesses 300+ things, ~ 10 mins or so each time.

For `PdfLaTex` I've tried using `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build_folder %.tex` but it seems to exit with errors but without error messages.

My subfolder is literally called `build_folder`. Is that part correct within the code line, do I need quotes or anything?

Thanks for the help

Edit: After I `Clean Auxillary Files` I get the following message box and errors:

Message box:

```
Could not start Recompile Bibliography:PdfLaTeX:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build_folder "main".tex.
```

Messages:

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build_folder "main".tex

Process exited with error(s)



Process started: biber "main"

INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'main.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber?
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)



Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build_folder "main".tex

Process exited with error(s)



Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build_folder "main".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer also works on Mac https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471579/91556

Comment: @hesham, unfortunately not. `--aux-directory=build_folder` was an unrecognized option. I have't tested BibTex or Biber yet but i'll try with `-output-folder`

Comment: @hesham, no luck. I now get a different error:

`ERROR - Cannot find control file 'main.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber?`


I see the file in the subfolder

Comment: Guess this problem was also reported as https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1273, and has been resolved there.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ wasn't sure of best place to ask. Thanks again for the help