# Compiled latex file in a separate folder on Mac (TeXstudio, MacTEX)

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, mactex

On MacOS, I've installed MacTEX and TexStudio.
I'm looking for a MacTex command that will allow me to separate compilation files from the file.tex files in a folder.

[image]

I've attempted both "—output-directory=dir" and "—aux-directory=dir" as instructed in the previous stackExchange like [link1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184204/texstudio-biber-build-folder) and other website [link2](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15655).

[image]

However, TeXstudio does not separate built auxiliary files nor does it create a subdirectory for them. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use one hyphen instead of two for the flag as advised in the first link you provide?

Comment: I have tried that too.